# Making visual realistic map containing mountain hiking trails/tracks?

Tags: maps

I would like to try making a map that visually reproduces a mountain/hill and contains hiking trails, just like this one:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/PdcnM.jpg

I imagine some steps like this:

1. Generate a realistic 45 degrees (or so) representation of the area (from GIS) - how?
2. An artist (painter) draws the visual simplified representation of what you get on firsts step and then trails are added.

Did anyone do maps like this and knows exactly how to make one?

Comment: use Google Earth?

Comment: What software is available to you? You are correct that the image you linked to is heavily drawn by an artist rather than GIS software.

Comment: http://www.mountaincartography.org/publications/papers/papers_lenk_08/tait.pdf

Comment: Great reference, @Mapperz.  +1

Comment: I would try any software there is on Linux (Ubuntu), but I start thinking it might not be so much of GIS (or none of all) for these maps, one photo is enough to start painting this.

Comment: @Mapperz - really great resource, it got a lot clearer what it means to create these maps.